# How can I change the width of a flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a `<div>` called .PhotoBox which I am using as a flex container:

```
.PhotoBox{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This is within a React app which then renders a set of images to create a collage. This is the only CSS applied to the children:

```
img {
    height:200px;
    width:120px;
}
```

Currently by default, the flex box renders 7 items (images) horizontally before wrapping to a new row.

I want the user to be able to select how many items per row they want. The images are always 120px wide, so I was going to resize the flexbox to force this.

However when I do this to .PhotoBox, the flex container:

```
width:90%;
```

...the flex box now only renders one item (image) per row? When I've only marginally reduced the width? I expected after some trial and error / marginal reduction that I would find the point at which only 6 images per row are rendered, then 5, then 4 etc... but it went straight to one and essentially became a column display?

Should I be using a different method to reduce the width of the flex container a little so that fewer items render horizontally by default?

Comment: Which browsers show this behavior?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: code would have helped , but look its 90% of what

Comment: It's unclear since the lack of the other DOM elements on your page. For example - maybe that div `.PhotoBox` is inside another div that restricts its width? Also, have you tried adding `flex-direction: row;` to `.PhotoBox` to see if something changes?

Answer (score -1):

By styling .PhotoBox as

```
min-width: 90%;
max-width: 90%;
```

You can set a fixed width of 90% to the container.